# Why is Open Office pushing certain items in a numbered list forward?

Tags: openoffice-writer

Open Office is really messing with me. I'm just trying to make an outline for one of my textbooks, and it's doing stuff like this:

[image]

Notice how certain items on the second level are pushed forward. What's going on? Why is it doing that? I downloaded OO quite recently, and haven't tampered with the "Bullets and Numbering" settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because You set `tab` as a separator between item and its text. When the tab fits into a predefined mesh of tabs, it stays there, when it doesn't -- it starts another tab.

Here's an anlogue from emacs (`>>` symbol shows tab):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Openoffice inserts a tab between the number of the item and the text. If you set the 1st tab of the whole index to a new position where all numbers fit before it, it will align correctly.